# How are the two proton beams at the LHC accelerated in opposite directions?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, accelerator-physics

At the Large Hadron Collider (LHC), how are the protons in the two beams accelerated in opposite directions?

Comment: Hello, I presume you wonder how two protons, i.e. things with identical charges, are accelerated in opposite directions? I mean, the fact they have identical charges makes you wonder how it's done?

Answer (score 2):

The LHC has two separate pipes. Although some systems are shared between the two of them, other relevant ones are kept independent. This allows not only to accelerate two proton beams in opposite directions, but also to have collisions between beams of different species, like protons and lead ions.